# How to programmatically remove data from fields using delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

When I delete data using Delete, they still remain in the dbf table but are marked as deleted

```
Procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);

var god,data,max,date:string;

begin
date:=formatdatetime('dd.mm.yyyy',(DateTimePicker1.Date));
god:=copy(formatdatetime('yyyy',(DateTimePicker1.Date)),1,4);
data:=formatdatetime('ddmm',(DateTimePicker1.Date));
  ADOQuery1.Close;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Append('Select max(date_pogr) as max from g_rabn.dbf where god='+''''+'''');
  ADOQuery1.Open;
  max:=ADOQuery1.FieldByName('max').asstring;
  if date<>max then
  begin
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Text:='delete from g_rabn.dbf where year='+''''+'''';
  ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Text:='use g_rabn.dbf pack';
  ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
  showmessage('Wrong date');
  end
  else
  begin
  ADOQuery1.SQL.text:='update g_rabn.dbf set year='+''''+year+'''' +' where year='+''''+'''';
  ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.text:='update g_rabn.dbf set data='+''''+data+'''' +' where data='+''''+'''';
  ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;

end;

end;
end.
```

How to delete data from a table physically

Comment: Pack the table. This requires exclusive access so can't be done when others are modifying or have the table open - this includes not having the table open yourself.

Comment: Looks like you can't pack the table using ADO. Need to use some other data access components that do support the pack operation.

Comment: True. ADO is a generic access layer, and typically doesn't contain data management features like that (not even for Microsoft's own databases, for Access you will need JET, for instance). 
Maybe [TDBF](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tdbf/) supports this, but I'm not sure, and it's documentation is currently timing out for me..

Comment: Packing tables is not something you would normally do with DBF tables on a dayly basis, only when you notice deleted records are taking up a lot of space. When tables are small, it will suffice to do it on the fly. But as the table grows, packing will take a lot of time as the table is recreated, without the deleted records. So what is the actual problem, because your code covers a lot more then just deleting records...

Comment: User asked a follow-up question under a new account,  which makes this question obsolete/duplicate. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58742995/when-packing-a-dbf-table-an-error-is-file-is-in-use