# when packing a dbf table, an error is file is in use

Tags: delphi

When trying to make a request, it displays an error:

> File is in use

How can I solve that program?

```
 procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
 var data,ffg:string;
 begin
 data:=formatdatetime('ddmm',(DateTimePicker1.Date));
 Adoquery2.SQL.Clear;
 adoquery2.SQL.text:='Delete from g_rabn where data=data';// deleting data from g_rabn
 adoquery2.ExecSQL;
 ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));

 end;
 procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
 begin
 Adoquery3.close;
 Adoquery3.SQL.Clear;
 adoquery3.SQl.text:='pack table g_rabn';// packing tablr g_rabn
 adoquery3.Open;
 ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
 end;

 end.
```

I can not delete data from the table, they are marked as deleted but require packaging. How to do it programmatically? He writes that file is in use when packing what to do?

Comment: Shouldn't ``Button5Click`` do an ``AdoQuery3.ExceSQL;`` instead of ``AdoQuery3.Open;``!?

Comment: Are you still having a problem with this?

Comment: `GetLastError` is only useful for WinAPI calls that are documented to set the last error. ADO does not, and is not documented as doing so. Random calls to `GetLastError` provide random results, and any value you're getting from doing so is meaningless (and useless). ADO raises an exception, and the exception message has already told you what the problem is - packing a DBF file requires exclusive access, meaning nothing else can have it open (including other parts of your own app).

Comment: Exclusive access is required because of how the operation is done. A new empty copy of the DBF file is created, and then non-deleted rows are copied into it. When all of the non-deleted rows have been copied, the original file is closed and deleted, the new copy is renamed to the old file's name, and all indexes are reindex. If the file is in use, it can't be replaced and reindexed.

Answer (score 4):

You should execute the statement, not open it as a query. One way to achieve that, is to run it using an TADOCommand, not an TADOQuery, or use the `ExecSQL` method of the TADOQuery.

Also, all other connections to the DBF must be closed, otherwise you can't get the exclusive access that you need for packing the table.

I found [this thread from 2005 on another forum](http://www.andreavb.com/forum/viewtopic_5500.html), where somebody made this work with two notable parameters:

- Using the provider `VFPOLEDB.1`
- Using just the command `pack filename.dbf` (without the `table` keyword).

Lastly, I'm not so sure about the line `ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));`. This will show you the last API error, but that's on a low level. You are using the ADO components, so if anything is going wrong, you should expect ADO to throw an exception. For all you know ADO already worked around the issue one way or the other, and the error message you're seeing is not even relevant.

Comment: when I started using ADOCommand a new error appeared 'Cannot open file .... / g_rabn  procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ADOCOnnection1.Connected:=False;
FDCOnnection2.Connected:=False;
FDCOnnection1.Connected:=False;
ADOCommand1.Execute;
ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
end;

Comment: Added some additional info to the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hmm.  I set up a test on a DBF file that I can open w/o problem via a System DSN using the MS ODBC driver on Win10 + D7. Rather to my surprise, attempting to use a TAdoCommand to do a 'PACK d:\aaad7\ado\dbf\matest.dbf', I get 'Invalid SQL Statement; DELETE, INSERT, PROCEDURE, SELECT or UPDATE expected'.  I've tried executing this SQL and variants using various ADO objects with the same result.  Something not quite right here ...

Comment: Btw, by "here" I meant "on my PC", not with your answer ;-)

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, @MartynA! I will sleep better tonight. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I am surprised that I could not get the solution suggested in Golez Troi's answer
to work, especially as it refers to a newsgroup post from someone who had seemingly managed to pack a dBASE table using ADO; as I said in a comment, if I try to call 'Pack xxxx' to pack a dBASE table via ADO, however I do it, I get

> Invalid SQL Statement; DELETE, INSERT, PROCEDURE, SELECT or UPDATE expected
>   .

I was also surprised to notice something in the [MS ODBC dBASE docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/dbase-driver-programming-considerations?view=sql-server-ver15) that I'd not noticed before, namely that the MS ODBC driver for dBASE files *requires* the BDE

> Note
>   Accessing dBASE ISAM files through the ODBC Desktop Database Drivers requires installation of the Borland database engine

So, seeing as accessing dBASE files via Ado requires the BDE anyway, there seems to me to be
no point avoiding using the BDE to pack the dBASE table using the standard BDE method, namely to call DbiPackTable.  I added a TDatabase and TTable
to my ADO test project, after which I was able to execute this code without any problem

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    //  Insert code here to close any Ado object (TAdoConnection, TAdoCommand, etc) pointing
    //  at the dBASE table/file
    //  Also check that not Ado object pointing at it is open in the IDE
    //
    //  Then ...
    Database1.DatabaseName := 'MADBF2';
    Database1.Connected := True;
    Table1.TableName := 'MATest.Dbf';
    Table1.Exclusive := True;
    Table1.Open;
    //  Following uses a call to DbiPackTable to pack the target table
    Check(DbiPackTable(Table1.DBHandle, Table1.Handle, nil, nil,True));
  finally
    Table1.Close;
    Database1.Connected := False;
  end;
end;
```

FWIW, while I was writing this answer, I noticed that the BDE.Int file (which gives the declarations but not the implementation of the BDE interface) was on the D7 distribution CD but was apparently not installed by default).